# Discord API | User Flags return badges

Tags: node.js, discord, bit-manipulation

I am using Node.JS and Discords OAuth2 API. When I return the `/users/@me` it returns the users object. Example:

```
{
  "id": "80351110224678912",
  "username": "Nelly",
  "discriminator": "1337",
  "avatar": "8342729096ea3675442027381ff50dfe",
  "verified": true,
  "email": "nelly@discord.com",
  "flags": 64,
  "premium_type": 1,
  "public_flags": 64
}
```

Now I am after the `"public_flags"` integer which is "64" on Discords API reference each flag has a different Left shift operator from the example number before it would equal to (1 << 6 : House Bravery), if a user has multiple badges it will add the total together. Flag IDs:

```
0   None
1 << 0  Discord Employee
1 << 1  Partnered Server Owner
1 << 2  HypeSquad Events
1 << 3  Bug Hunter Level 1
1 << 6  House Bravery
1 << 7  House Brilliance
1 << 8  House Balance
1 << 9  Early Supporter
1 << 10 Team User
1 << 12 System
1 << 14 Bug Hunter Level 2
1 << 16 Verified Bot
1 << 17 Early Verified Bot Developer
```

My question is how am I able to go through all math operations consisting the Flag ID's to then work out what badges a user has, or if there is an easier way to convert the number from the total resulting into what  badges the user has.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone who wants the Answer for this Question here it is :D

First of all you want to work out all the Left Shift operations for the assigned Badges above. I have done them all here!

```js
const Discord_Employee = 1;
const Partnered_Server_Owner = 2;
const HypeSquad_Events = 4;
const Bug_Hunter_Level_1 = 8;
const House_Bravery = 64;
const House_Brilliance = 128;
const House_Balance = 256;
const Early_Supporter = 512;
const Bug_Hunter_Level_2 = 16384;
const Early_Verified_Bot_Developer = 131072;
```

Then you need to get the public_flags integer from the request example: `const flags = user.public_flags;`

After that we can check if each badge exist in the `flags` bit integer. (I am bad at explaing this)

```js
if((flags & Discord_Employee) == Discord_Employee){
   var badge_Discord_Employee = "true";
}
else{
  var badge_Discord_Employee = "false";
}
```

Repeat this code replacing `Discord_Employee` with the next badge you want to check.